# How to remain on the same page after clicking submit on a form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an html file/page where there will be multiple input fields in a form. This form action field is linked to another .php file where all the inputted data is written to a database. But once when i click submit the form i get directed to the .php file which is not what i want.Is there any way by which i could write the data into the database ,but remain in the same html file?

Comment: You might want to redirect from the php file back to the html file

Comment: You can for example redirect back, handle the PHP on the same page or use some AJAX. All those methods will end up on the same HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this, you have to use javascript and ajax.

your form:

```
<form id="yourform">...</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#yourform').on('submit', function(e) {
        var data = $("#yourform :input").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            data: data,
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: The key here is the `preventDefault()` call.

Answer (score 0):

of course. use ajax. do some web searches on ajax combined with html and you will find the answers you are looking for. jquery is one possible javascript/ajax platform that could simplify this process for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1 - Submit you form using AJAX. With this approach the page will stay "refresh" and the user will be on the same page

2 - After the submit, redirect the user back to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the submit button send the form data to a div tag on the same page using ajax. The code from Dynamic Drive should work if you read through it.

[Dynamic Drive - Dynamic Ajax Content](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm)